# Coolant temperature sign is gone and fan is running!

Tags: pontiac

My Pontiac G5 2008 Coolant temperature sign is gone and the fan is running in the cool weather but it goes to be fine in hot weather!

Comment: Welcome to the site. We would like to help you, but your question is unclear. Please use the [edit] function to explain more clearly and add more details if you can. For instance, what do you mean your "*temperature sign is gone*"?

Comment: So in cold weather the temp gauge is not showing the cold symbol on the dash board. But in summer it shows up, is that correct?